# JQuery Mobile, alternating images breaks "Back" button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-mobile, image-rotation

For a JQuery Mobile site, I need an new image to load on page navigation. The image only displays on the homescreen.

So for example, you load m.smellyeggs.com which has image_A.png as the top banner. You select menu item 1, then press back and now image_B.jpg is showing as the top banner.

I was able to get it working using [cookies](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp). I get an array of potential images, then use cookies to traverse the array. This works on page reload, but any cache loading of a page (e.g. href="/" or using "Back" in mobile or the browser) would not call the javascript. Thus the image would not actually alternate.

```
var images = new Array(); 
<% banner_mobile_uris( controller.conference ).each do |url| %>
  images.push( "<%= url %>" );
<% end %>

inc_banner_cookie();
load_banner();
```

To fix this, I use the following code, which deletes the image, forcing an image refresh whenever the homepage is loaded.

```
$( 'a' ).live( 'click', function( ev ){
  var banner = $('#m_banner').load(htm_file);
  banner.empty().remove();
});
```

**This code removes the "Back" button from any subsequent page navigation that occurs.**

Well that's unacceptable! Any advice on a better approach? I'd rather not implement my own "Back" button unless that is absolutely necessary.

Thanks for reading (and hopefully helping ).

Comment: post the full code of your jquery mobile html, i have to see your structure

Answer (score 1):

The answer lies in using pageinit to detect successful JQuery Mobile page loads...

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){
    inc_banner_cookie();
    load_banner();
});
```

This will not disable the back button. And cause image reloads on any type of page navigation. Well almost any type...

As it turns out, this appraoch is fragile when AJAX redirects occur, and subsequent pageinits may not work. See [my question concerning this issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17578164/jquery-mobile-url-redirect-breaks-pageinit)