# JQuery Mobile - AJAX URL redirect breaks pageinit

Tags: ajax, jquery, jquery-mobile, redirect, page-init

### **TL;DR - AJAX URL redirect breaks 'pageinit' and any subsequent 'pageinit's that occur after the redirect**

(see https://stackoverflow.com/a/14469041/2133816 for information on pageinit)

**How to recover from this?**

### In Detail:

My mobile site has user accounts, so when a homepage button is selected that requires a user login it will first try to access the site in question...

```
m.smellyeggs.com/stuff?id=2497349187324&tr=454543522525
```

But once it is detected that the user has not logged in, the site reroutes the user to...

```
m.smellyeggs.com/login
```

Sadly, this event breaks functionality for all pageinit events:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function(){
  // things are done here
});
```

So after a redirect event occurs, no more pageinit events are detected, and unfortunately my data is loaded from the cache.

**How can I recover from a "broken" pageinit, specifically occurring after an AJAX redirect.**

Thank you!

Comment: could u post you HTML here?

Comment: Replace pageinit with pageshow.